# jQuery UI Range Slider values to input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input, range, uislider

using the jQuery range slider i have been trying to get the values in a hidden input field which will be used for a search.

the hidden input field has the same id as the slider fields which the value but the hidden ones done show anything!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sliderranger" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount1" ).val( "THB " + ui.values[ 0 ] );
            $( "#amount2" ).val( "THB " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            var price1 = ui.values[ 0 ];
            var price2 = ui.values[ 1 ];
            //alert(price1 + " " + price2); 
            $( "#price1" ).value = price1;
        }
    });
    $( "#amount1" ).val( "THB " + $( "#sliderranger" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
    $( "#amount2" ).val( "THB " + $( "#sliderranger" ).slider( "values", 1 ));
});
```

above is the js code if this helps if you need more info let me know and il see what i can do .

hope some one can help i can see much on this topic ??

Answer (score 0):

> the hidden input field has the same id
>   as the slider fields which the value

I hope you don't mean that there are two elements with the same `id` attribute on the same page. If so, you'll need to change this or you'll see unexpected results.

As for setting the value of hidden inputs with slider results, it looks like you're close. This line:

```
$( "#price1" ).value = price1;
```

Should be changed to:

```
$( "#price" ).val(price1);
```

Here's your code revised (and using visible `input` elements of type `text` instead of `hidden`): http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/Pyprr/

Comment: hi Andrew, thanks for your input but its still not showing up in the value! <input id=price1" value="...." type="hidden" />

Comment: @Daniel: How are you checking to see if its set? If I change the input type in my example to `hidden` and inspect it in Firebug or Chrome I see the value changing. How is your code different from my example?

Comment: its actually firebug which wasnt showing the value i checked in chrome and the value was there!

Comment: @Daniel: Ok, so is it working then? Some DOM inspection tools don't show a `value` attribute updated through JS.

Comment: i just need to test the form submit to make sure the values are taking. will let you know